# pmap_df inside mutate applying to entire dataframe not just row

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataframe where each row includes arguments that I want to pass into a function iteratively. The function itself returns a dataframe with a few rows. I would like to keep the arguments and results together in one dataframe by applying pmap_df like you can with pmap_dbl inside of a mutate to add a new column with the results from the function. With the code below, I am able to get a column with nested data in it, but every row contains the data for all of the results, not just the ones corresponding to that row.

```
library(tidyr)

example_function <- function(data, string, ...){
  
  word_one <- paste(data$word_one, string)
  word_two <- paste(data$word_two, string)
  
  output <- data_frame(result_words = c(word_one, word_two))
  
}

fake_data <- tibble(group_id = rep(c(1, 2), each = 3),
                    word_one = c("hello", "goodbye", "today",
                                 "apple", "banana", "coconut"),
                    word_two = c("my", "name", "is",
                                 "ellie", "good", "morning"))

test <- fake_data %>% 
        group_by(group_id) %>% 
        nest() %>% 
        mutate(string = "not working") %>% 
        mutate(final_output = list(purrr::pmap_df(.l = ., .f = example_function)))
```

The output looks like:

```
Rows: 2
Columns: 4
Groups: group_id [2]
$ group_id     <dbl> 1, 2
$ data         <list> [<tbl_df[3 x 2]>], [<tbl_df[3 …
$ string       <chr> "not working", "not working"
$ final_output <list> [<tbl_df[12 x 1]>], [<tbl_df[…
```

What I would like to have would be for each of the final outputs to have only 6 rows in each dataframe, corresponding to the inputs from the nested data column. Is this possible?

Comment: I guess you need to loop over the `data` column instead of the whole dataset `.`

Comment: Will you have `n` number of `word` columns? Or just the two?

Comment: I will have 1 column and 6 rows for each row of the initial dataframe

Comment: Try `fake_data %>% 
        group_by(group_id) %>% 
        nest() %>% 
        mutate(string = "not working")  %>%  ungroup %>% mutate(final_output = pmap(across(-group_id), ~ ..1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_c(.x, " ", ..2))) %>% unlist(., recursive = FALSE) %>% tibble(result_words = .)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the OP's function, it may be easily done without any `pmap` (return the `output` from the function)

```
example_function <- function(data, string, ...){
  
  word_one <- paste(data$word_one, string)
  word_two <- paste(data$word_two, string)
  
  output <- data_frame(result_words = c(word_one, word_two))
  output
  
}
```

As it is a `nest_by`, directly apply the function

```
library(dplyr)
fake_data %>% 
         nest_by(group_id) %>%
    mutate(string = "not working") %>%
    mutate(final_output = list(example_function(data, string)))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Rowwise:  group_id
  group_id               data string      final_output    
     <dbl> <list<tibble[,2]>> <chr>       <list>          
1        1            [3 × 2] not working <tibble [6 × 1]>
2        2            [3 × 2] not working <tibble [6 × 1]>
```

---

With `pmap`, extract the contents as a `list` to an object 'x1' then apply the OP's function on the list elements i.e. `x1$data` and `x1$string`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
fake_data %>% 
         nest_by(group_id) %>%
    mutate(string = "not working") %>%
    ungroup %>%
    mutate(final_output = pmap(across(-group_id), 
       ~ {
      x1 <- list(...)
       example_function(x1$data, x1$string)
 }))
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  group_id               data string      final_output    
     <dbl> <list<tibble[,2]>> <chr>       <list>          
1        1            [3 × 2] not working <tibble [6 × 1]>
2        2            [3 × 2] not working <tibble [6 × 1]>
```

Comment: @Emily It is just that the structure of data inside the `pmap` is slightly different.   In the updated call, it was returned as a `list` and then the function is called on the list elements